# Enterprise Library 5.0 64 bit Configuration Utility

Tags: visual-studio-2010, enterprise-library, 64-bit

I have both version 4 and 5 of the ENT Lib installed on my machine.

Version 4 has a configuration utility. I can't find it in 5.0

I read this:

*Enterprise Library includes a stand-alone configuration console, and a configuration editor that
integrates with Microsoft Visual Studio®. The stand-alone console is provided as versions specifically
aimed at the 32-bit (x86) platform and versions compiled for any platform.*

I presume that I must have a 64 bit version of VS2010 Ultimate installed. How can I tell?

I see documentation that reads as follows, but I don't see the config utility in my Start menu and don't have this content men option available:

*Open the stand-alone configuration tool from your Start menu, or right-click on a
configuration file in Visual Studio Solution Explorer and click Edit Enterprise Library V5
Configuration.*

How do I get the new Configuration Utility for 5.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enterprise Library includes four versions of the configuration tools in order to support the Visual Studio integrated editor, and 32-bit and 64-bit platforms.

The integrated Visual Studio Enterprise Library configuration tool displays types that belong to the project and its referenced assemblies. See more on this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664633%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx).

The Configuration tool is packaged with the Enterprise Library MSI.

However, you can also download it as a standalone from [Microsoft Download Center](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/6/4/F64B7080-3465-49AF-90B7-D6A4224A8D1F/Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ConfigConsole.vsix): 
or the [Visual Studio Extension Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/029292f0-6e66-424f-8381-3454c8222f9a).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are still having the issue. There was no solution posted and I had the same issue with VS2012.

I like to use Nuget where possible, but i managed to get inconsistent libraries that way.
Careful use of nuget with EntLib 5.0 will no doubt work. But after 3-4 hrs i was pulling my hair out.
Anyway...
I uninstalled all nuget and msi version of ALL libraries related to Microsoft.practices.
So that meant Enterprise library and Unity.

I installed the LAB from EntLib 5 lab site.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6932
The VS integrated config editor seems to only work work with VS2010.
ie if you find the console.vsix on nuget or EntLib site, you can only use that with VS2010.

Get/use the standalone editor for VS2012. ( i think was installed with the lab msi?, sorry not 100% sure thats where it came from).

The question about targeting is important. But why the 64 bit version of the editor is important I havent figured out yet.
You actually get 4 consoles from the latest lab msi install.
1 for .net 3.5 and 4.0 versions and a 64 bit version of both of those.
The config settings and types used by editor a different console versions results in slight differences inside your app.config file. 
Most importantly Version and GAC tokens inside the config file.

```
<configSections>
    <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
</configSections>
```

Anyway hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded "Enterprise Library 5.0.msi" (rather than just the source code) and made sure that the config utility was selected (the default).

Dunno what the above was really talking about "aiming at 32 bit", but I got the utility, so I guess all is good.